# How do you read in an xyz-3 ASCII data into pycharm?

Tags: functions, arrays, python

I'm very new to PyCharm, does anyone have experience with reading in xyz-3 ASCII data into the script as an array? I need to perform principal component analysis on this dataset but am unsure of the exact parameters/function to use when reading in the data. The txt file is already in the project directory. It's in the form of data in this link https://www.cytospec.com/file.php#FileASCII5
[image]

Comment: This site is for questions about designing and implementing programming languages, not use of IDEs. There may be other sites on the network where a question about this is on-topic, although it looks like it would need more concrete detail to make for an answerable question.